# Were Germans permitted to give the Hitler salute with the left arm?

Tags: military, nazi-germany, hitler

I frequently come across pictures and videos where Nazi functionaries (such as SS and SA men) give the infamous *Hitler salute* (a.k.a the *Fascist salute*) with their right hand. Now this is hardly surprising since military styled salutes tend to be 'right-handed'.

[image]

[image]

But suppose an SS officer were to lose his (entire) right arm in battle. Would he be permitted to give the Hitler salute with his left arm? Would he be allowed to do so in front of a superior officer (or even Hitler himself)? What provisions (if any) were in place for those who couldn't give the Hitler salute normally (i.e- with the right hand)?

[image]

[^ The left-handed salute remains elusive...at least on Google Images]

Comment: Wikipedia, not specific to Nazis tho: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salute#Saluting_with_left_hand

Comment: I think this fall's outside history; unless there is an example, this is an invitation to speculation.

Comment: What if the soldier had arthritic fingers and couldn't straighten his hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_salute#Description):

> If physical disability prevented raising the right arm, it was acceptable to raise the left.

The source for this is Ian Kershaw's *The "Hitler Myth": Image and Reality in the Third Reich*, Oxford University Press, 2001.